# Get output from editable cell factories in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `TableView` which has coloumns with editable cells: `TextFieldTableCell`,`ChoiceBoxTableCell` and `CheckBoxTableCell`.

They are made like this:

```java
usernameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
usernameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User,String>("username"));
permissionLevelCol.setCellFactory(ChoiceBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(/*returns a String[]*/usersManager.getPermissionNamesList()));
permissionLevelCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User,String>("permissionLevel"));
giveRefundsCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(giveRefundsCol));
giveRefundsCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PermissionLevel, Boolean>("giveRefunds"));
```

How can I get the output whenever the user changes something in these cells. I need both some sort of trigger and a way to get the new value. Ex. print the new value whenever it changes

Edit:

My attempt:

In the User class I put this method which is called by the constructor:

```java
public void setup(){
    username.addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            System.out.println("changed username to: " + newValue);
        }
    });

    password.addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            System.out.println("changed password to: " + newValue);
        }
    });

    permissionLevel.addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            System.out.println("changed permission level to: " + newValue);
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately this still doesn't work.

Comment: search about property binding in javafx

Comment: @AhmedEmad Thanks, I know a bit about properties but what's the name of the propert that I'm looking for?

Comment: you need string property binding to the value of the text field

Comment: @AhmedEmad Oh ok. feel free to.post this as an answer, this looks like what I needed

Comment: Snippets are useless because they dont provide enough context to answer your question - No way around a [mcve] ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `usernameCol.setOnEditCommit(EventHandler)` to listen to the changes that happen to the table cell and then you can pass the value to another function to validate or save the data what ever you want or bind the value using `StringProperty` and implement the `onChangeListener()`

Comment: might be that the op wants to validate but that's a speculation :-) without there's rarely a need for edit handlers provided the setup is correct (which I doubt here, now speculating also)

Comment: The reason that I cant use onEditCommit is because of the CheckBoxTableCell. It doesnt call that method